# why [] test makes this script to fail?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Please consider these two scripts:

`run.sh:`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
. "$(dirname $(realpath $BASH_SOURCE))"/init-sudo-script.sh
```

`init-sudo-script.sh`

```bash
[ ${#BASH_SOURCE[@]} -eq 1 ]\
    && echo "must be sourced by another script."\
    && exit 10

[ $EUID -ne 0 ]\
    && echo "must be executed as root."\
    && exit 20
```

This is correct and it is what I expect to happen:

```
$ ./run.sh
must be executed as root.
$ echo $?
20
```

But this I can't understand:

```
$ sudo ./run.sh
$ echo $?
1
```

I know the problem is `[ $EUID -ne 0 ]` because the script works when I remove it.

I also understand `set -e` makes the script to exit on any error.

What I don't understand is why the first guard condition (`[ ${#BASH_SOURCE[@]} -eq 1 ]`) doesn't exit with 1 when it fails but the second does.

**Does anybody understand what is happening here?**

**===UPDATE===**

I found a way to make it works as I expect:

```bash
if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "must be executed as root."\
    && exit 20
fi
```

I would leave this behind but I'm investing on getting better in Bash. So if anyone can clarify what's going on I'd appreciate to hear.

Comment: `echo "...." && exit 2` is a bit odd since presumably you want to exit even if the echo fails (e.g. if stdout is closed). There's no need for the `&&`

Comment: `set -e` [is a bad idea in the first place](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises). So is doing no error handling at all, of course -- but the Right Thing is to handle errors _explicitly_, as with appropriate use of `something || exit` or `something || return`. `set -e`'s rules next to impossible to understand, since they vary based on shell version, usage of functions up the call stack, and other details that aren't reliably knowable ahead-of-time (or reasonable to expect a reviewer doing a code read to keep in their head).

Comment: Hey Charles, thank you for chip in and share the article. I understand the problems with `set -e` but I still see value on it for the cases where it works. I'm agree more with rkings (at the bottom of the article) personal recommendation to use it but be aware of its gotchas.
Great stuff you shared here. Thank you!

Comment: Side note: the line continuations make your code harder to read than it needs to be.  Bash will continue to the next line without them if you put the `&&` at the end of the preceding line instead of at the start of the next line.

Comment: That's new to me John. Will try. Thank you!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I also understand `set -e` makes the script to exit on any error.

Not "on any error". There are exceptions, one of them is:

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is […] part of any command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`, […]

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html))</sup>

If `[ ${#BASH_SOURCE[@]} -eq 1 ]` fails then the shell will not exit because of `set -e`.

Similarly if `[ $EUID -ne 0 ]` fails then the shell will not exit because of `set -e`. But it will exit just after *because the script ends*, i.e. because there is nothing more to execute. And then the exit status of the script will be the exit status of the last command executed; and it happens to be the failing `[`. This is why you get `1`.

Place `:` (a no-op command that always succeeds) at the end of `init-sudo-script.sh` and re-run your tests. `sudo ./run.sh` will return `0` because the last command will be `:`.

---

Your updated code with `if` is different because the exit status from `if` is:

> […] zero if no condition tested true.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-if))</sup>

Comment: The `:` bugs me but that's ok. I do prefer the `[] &&` syntax but we do have the `if` syntax as an alternative

Comment: @Saulo, `if` does the same thing in this context. It needs to to have reasonable language semantics: if `if foo; then ...` exited whenever `foo` returned a nonzero exit status, then `if` would lose much of its meaning -- there would be no reason to support an `else` block at all because it would never be reachable; every use of `if` would have an implicit `else exit "$?"; fi`, and the `then` block would be run after success _just like the entire rest of the script_ including the content _not_ in the `then` block.